# How do I ask for a set list in Python, ask for a number (x), remove x number of inputs, and re-list those?

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python, and I am currently learning about lists. This is the question that I am trying to solve:

> Your favourite band is in town, and tickets are selling fast!  Alas,
>   you were too late to snag one, so you put your name in the waitlist,
>   in case any extra tickets are released.
>
> Write a program to manage the waitlist for the concert.
>
> Your program should read in a list of the names in the waitlist, and
>   the number of extra tickets released.
>
> Then, it should announce the names of people who score the extra
>   tickets.
>
> Here's an example of how your program should work:
>
> ```
> People in line: Dave, Lin, Toni, Markhela, Ravi
> Number of extra tickets: 3
> Tickets released for: Dave, Lin, Toni
> ```
>
> Note: The names are separated
>   by a comma and a space (', ').
>
> If there are no more tickets released, your program should work like
>   this:
>
> ```
> People in line: Mali, Micha, Mary, Monica
> Number of extra tickets: 0
> Fully Booked!
> ```
>
> This band is so popular that there will always be at least as many
>   people as extra tickets. You won't have to worry about index errors.

I have tried the following, but it always prints the entire list, not just a subset.

```
ppl = []
sep = ', '
ppl_in_line = input('People in line: ')
ppl.append(ppl_in_line)
x = int(input('Number of extra tickets: '))
if x == 0:
    print('Fully Booked!')
else:    
    y = ppl[:x]
    print('Tickets released for: ' + (sep.join(y)))
```

Comment: Please debug your code and analyse what each line is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to split your people in line into multiple elements:

```
ppl_in_line = input('People in line: ')
ppl = ppl_in_line.split(sep)
```

This is assuming that your input for `People in line:` is something like

```
Dave, Lin, Toni, Markhela, Ravi
```

If you want to use `ppl.append`, you have to mention them name by name in a loop:

```
while True:
    ppl_in_line = input('People in line: ')
    if not ppl_in_line:
        break
    ppl.append(ppl_in_line)
```

You can enter the names like

```
Dave
Lin
Toni
Markhela
Ravi
```

An empty input will finish the list.

Answer (score 3):

ppl_in_line is a string. So when you append to ppl, you are appending a single string.

To enter a separated list of ppl on a single line do this:

`ppl_in_line = input('People in line: ').split(sep)`